# Xamarin / MonoDevelop ASP.Net toolbox

Tags: asp.net, xamarin, monodevelop

I have tried several versions of Xamarin and monodevelop versions. I have the same problem on each version: My Toolbox is empty. When i click on "add components", i cannot add any control (i ve tried to select dlls like System.Web but it does not work)

What should i do ?

Answer (score 2):

Mono project gave up its attempt to support ASP.NET WebForms (aka System.Web) with a visual designer like Visual Studio.

I think that's why you cannot add any controls to the tool box.

It would be good enough for ASP.NET MVC, Web API and SignalR though, as they don't need a visual designer.